# fopen() return "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, fopen

I have some problem with fopen() function in C.

I'am parsed directory and put all the paths to char array(char**). After that i should to open all these files. And...
fopen returns "No such file or directory" for some files. And I Am really don't understand, why.

1. All paths are right. I checked it.
2. I have all privileges to
       open these files.
3. If I copy path to file from error log and try
       to open only this file via my programm - it works.
4. Others
       programms don't work with these files(i think).

What can I do wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char** set = malloc(10000*sizeof(char*));
    char* path = argv[1];
    listdir(path, set); /* Just parse directory. Paths from the root. No problem in this function.  all paths in the variable "set" are right */
    int i=0;
    while(i<files){ /* files is number of paths */
        FILE* file = fopen(set[i++],"rb");
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        int fileSize = ftell(file);
        rewind(file);
        /*reading bytes from file to some buffer and close current file */
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that you're not providing a [mcve]

Comment: Please, show your code.

Comment: Debugger.  Break on the fopen().  Inspect the set[] array byte-by-byte.  If this is awkward, strcpy() the array element to a local char array, (filepath[256], say), and inspect that.  Find out why the path is incorrect and fix it.

Comment: 'fopen returns "No such file or directory" for some files' - give an example of a file spec that does fopen, and one that does not.

Comment: @MartinJames I tried to do this. I compared byte-by-byte path from system and path from my program. They are identical.

Comment: ..and think about debugging before posting to SO.  It's much, much,. much,. much,. much,. much easier for you to do it than us - you already have everything set up with your compiler, linker, libraries, OS, folders, debugger, COMPLETE APP CODE SET etc.

Comment: You are not checking `FILE* file = fopen(set[i++],"rb");` so how do you know what it returns?

Comment: *All paths are right. I checked it.*  So, an operating system likely used by hundreds of millions of people - if not more - is wrong?  And your unique code and examples that you *didn't* post are correct?

Comment: `files` is not included in your code.

Comment: @tFNiYaFF - identical?  No extraneous unprintable chars?  No hidden CR, LF?  Just the absolute path followed immediately by the NUL terminator?

Comment: @MartinJames, yes. But i tried debugging. I posted to SO because, may be, i do not know some subtlety of the problem. If no some subtlety here exist, then question can be closed.

Comment: @tFNiYaFF there i snot all that much subtlely to a system call like fopen().  If you give it valid parameters, it will either work correctly or your OS is finished.

Comment: I guess that you are trying to open files with relative pathnames from the wrong directory.

Comment: what is your 'listdir' definition? In any case it looks like you misinterpret how the pointers are used. This does not make much sense: `char** set = malloc(10000*sizeof(char*));`  as well as passing it to a function which is supposed to fill a `char*[]`.

Comment: If you by chance use linux, just start your program with strace, you will probably quickly see what goes wrong (otherwise post the output here)

Comment: There are reasonable situations where fopen can fail with this error AND the path be correct, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. You increments 'i' twice. May be mistakenly?
2. You can get file size w/o open it using stat().
3. ftell() returns "long", don't cast it in "int" as it can be shorten and you loose correct value.

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

/* example of listdir, replace it with your real one */
int listdir(const char *path, char *set[])
{
    set[0] = "0.txt";
    set[1] = "1.txt";
    set[2] = "2.txt";
    set[3] = "3.txt";
    set[4] = "4.txt";

    return 5;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int files;
    char *path = argv[1];
    char **set = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char *));

    files = listdir(path, set);

    for (int i = 0; i < files; i++) {
        struct stat st;
        stat(set[i], &st);
        printf("FileSize of %s is %zu\n", set[i], st.st_size);
    }
    free(set);
}
```

Comment: *Don't try to use char **name as char *name[] that are not compatible.* ?!?!?!?  Please explain that.

Comment: Andrew, please ignore that remark, it was stupid think :)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I am guessing you are on some Posix system, hopefully Linux)</sup>

Probably your `listdir` is wrong. FWIW, if you use [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) in it, you need to concatenate the directory name and the file name (with a  `/` in between, perhaps using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) for that purpose).

But surely,

```
    FILE* file = fopen(set[i++],"rb"); ////WRONG
```

is doubly wrong. First, you are incrementing `i++` twice (and here it is too early). Then, you should read [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and handle the failure case, at least with:

```
   char* curpath = set[i];
   assert (curpath != NULL);
   FILE* file = fopen(curpath, "rb");
   if (!file) { perror(curpath); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  };
```

testing the result of `fopen` against failure is mandatory. Notice that I am passing the *same* `curpath` to [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) on failure.

You may also want to check that your current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is what you expect. Use [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) for that.

Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (on Linux) to understand what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are done by your program.